# Django: form.is_valid() is always false

Tags: python, django

I'm just a beginner in Django and I am currently developing user login functionalities. I've come across a bug and I cannot find out what is wrong. I've read other questions and solutions from that topic, but those solutions do not apply to my problem. I tried them but they do not work.
My problem: form.is_valid() is always false

views.py

```
def login_view(request):
form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
print(request.user.is_authenticated)

if form.is_valid():
    username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
    password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    login(request, user)
    print("Works")
    print(request.user.is_authenticated)

return render(request, "music/login.html", {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
User = get_user_model()

class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
username = forms.CharField()
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
    username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
    password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)


    if not user:
        raise forms.ValidationError("This user does not exists")
    if user.check_password(password):
        raise forms.ValidationError("Incorrect password")
    if not user.is_active:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Tjis user is not longer active")

    return super(UserLoginForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

login.html

```
<h3>Login</h3>
                <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    {% include 'music/form-template.html' %}
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

'music/form-template.html

```
{% for field in form %}
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <span class="text-danger small">{{field.errors}}</span>

    </div>
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">{{field.label_tag}}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">{{field}}</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Check `form.errors` field to check the errors after `form.is_valid()`. This will help to analyze the issue.

Comment: What does `music/form-template.html` look like?

Comment: Thank you. It says that is incorrect password even though it is not. I checked in admin console and it was the correct password.

Comment: If you can see the password in the admin, you are doing something wrong because that means it must be stored in plain text. Django will always hash the submitted password before comparing with the db value, so it will never match the plain text. How did you create your user?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I added it. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I know it is hashed. This, I created a new user merely for testing so I would be sure about the password.

Comment: Does `check_password` return true if the password is wrong?? It would seem to me that it's not well named, since to me I would assume "check password" would return true if the password was correct. And if that's the case, that's your issue.

Comment: @RobG If password is incorrect it returns true and than it says that user is incorrect.

Comment: Also note, `authenticate` already checks the password as well as the username, so your first validation message might not be accurate; it covers *both* "user does not exist" and "user exists but password is wrong". You shouldn't do that separate `check_password` call at all.

Comment: @DanielRoseman deleting check password does the trick. Now it works. Thank you for the help!